# How to generate a table using data from database and for loop (php)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to fetch some data from my database and then iterate over the result to generate a table that looks like the one shown below. I'm still quite new to php/html so pls bear with my coding abilities. I have the following code so far:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
 echo "
    <table id='myTable' class=''>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>i</th>
                <th>Importance</th>
                <th>How Much More</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>";

 $getObs = $db->prepare("SELECT ComplianceID, ObstacleDescription FROM obstacles WHERE ComplianceID = :option");
 $getObs->bindParam(':option', $option);
 $getObs->execute();
 $result = $getObs->fetchAll();
 for ($i=0; $i < $result; $i++) {
    echo '<tr id="'.$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i].'">';
    echo '<td class = "aObs">'.$result[$i].'</td>
    <td class = "aObs">'."<input type='radio' name='op1' value='1'>"
    .$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i]."<?php echo "or"?>"; "<input type='radio' name='op2' value='2'>"
    .$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i+1].</td>'


    <td class="aObs"><input type='radio' name='op1' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='op2' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='op3' value='3'>
<input type='radio' name='op4' value='4'>
<input type='radio' name='op5' value='5'>
<input type='radio' name='op6' value='6'>
<input type='radio' name='op7' value='7'>
<input type='radio' name='op8' value='8'>
<input type='radio' name='op9' value='9'>
 </td>';
 }
 echo"</tbody>";
 }
?>
```

In this example I have the values: Security, Finaicial, Legal and Technical as my ObstacleDescription in db. Each is compared with the next on each row and the last one is compared with the first. If anyone could pls point me in the right direction from here. Thanks in advance

[image: CPC Calculator]

Comment: can you show an image result of what you are getting the result atpresent

Comment: its just error messages at the moment to be honest.. mostly syntax but im working on getting rid of them. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up a lot if you close PHP and get rid of all quotes with `echo`

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
?> // It's a lot easier to just close PHP instead of dealing with single and double quotes
        <table id='myTable' class=''>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>i</th>
                    <th>Importance</th>
                    <th>How Much More</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php

 $getObs = $db->prepare("SELECT ComplianceID, ObstacleDescription FROM obstacles WHERE ComplianceID = :option");
 $getObs->bindParam(':option', $option);
 $getObs->execute();
 $result = $getObs->fetchAll();
 for ($i=0; $i < $result; $i++): ?> // This saves you a lot of hassle, again, with quotes.
<td class="aObs"><input type='radio' name='op1' value='1'>
  <input type='radio' name='op2' value='2'>
  <input type='radio' name='op3' value='3'>
  <input type='radio' name='op4' value='4'>
  <input type='radio' name='op5' value='5'>
  <input type='radio' name='op6' value='6'>
  <input type='radio' name='op7' value='7'>
  <input type='radio' name='op8' value='8'>
  <input type='radio' name='op9' value='9'>
</td>
```

When you're inside the `for()` loop, you can just use `<?php echo result['whatever']; ?>` arbitrarily if you want to put something inside each `<td>`. I imagine this is what you will want to do eventually.

Comment: hey sorry i misread your comments earlier. thanks for the suggestion. I will try this way and see how it works. sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
 echo "
    <table id='myTable' class=''>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>i</th>
                <th>Importance</th>
                <th>How Much More</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>";

  $getObs = $db->prepare("SELECT ComplianceID, ObstacleDescription FROM obstacles WHERE ComplianceID = :option");
 $getObs->bindParam(':option', $option);
 $getObs->execute();
 $result = $getObs->fetchAll();
 for ($i=0; $i < $result; $i++) {
    echo "<tr id='".$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i]."'>";
    echo "<td class = 'aObs'>".$result[$i]."</td>
    <td class = 'aObs'><input type='radio' name='op1' value='1'>
    ".$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i]." or <input type='radio' name='op2' value='2'>
    ".$result['ObstacleDescription'][$i+1]."</td>


<td class='aObs'>
<input type='radio' name='op1' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='op2' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='op3' value='3'>
<input type='radio' name='op4' value='4'>
<input type='radio' name='op5' value='5'>
<input type='radio' name='op6' value='6'>
<input type='radio' name='op7' value='7'>
<input type='radio' name='op8' value='8'>
<input type='radio' name='op9' value='9'>
</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody>";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks. but i still get error: undefined index ObstacleDescription. Im not sure why it's not accessing the db values

Comment: I use a different approch to fetch from database.But the table problem of yours is solved in my answer.